# Compression not available on SQL Server Standard? Options?

Tags: sql-server, database, compression

So as they say, everyday is a school day. Today I learned that my workplace, runs SQL Server Standard edition, where I would have assumed Enterprise was in place. Although in reality shouldn't be surprised!

For some context, we have a very large database that houses our warehouse data. As the database has grown to a large size, it's causing issues with space on the server along with some application performance. So looking at it from my perspective I suggested we archive and purge the PROD database, to house only 18 months data in the PROD environment.

Wrote my scripts and tested them and all fine. I then went to compress the tables I had deleted data from, to find error messages that compression is not available in SQL Server Standard and requires Enterprise edition.

Wondering what my next steps are here? My assumption is that even though I am deleting a lot of data, we won't actually benefit in terms of performance, and space requisition until the tables get compressed.

Shrinking is something I guess I've always shy'd away from, many articles or posts here would advise not to use it.

Wondering, what sort of options do I have here?

Is my assumption correct, in that without compressing, we won't regain space from the trimmed database?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't realise there was a dedicated DBA segment of the site now.

Answer (score 0):

Moving this to resolved as opening query in specific DBA portion of the site